# Key containing backslash character/ Escape character in Redis

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I am using sorted set in Redis. I have a key that contains backslash and the value also contains backslash. I am getting a weird response and unable to know the reason. My term is "MO\TEST". And I want to store and retrieve the same thing. I am flexible to change way of insertion but in result, I would like to have the same "MO\TEST"
I am using the following commands

```
ZADD "MO\\" 67 "MO\TEST"
ZADD "MO\\" 67 "MO\\TEST"
```

The output for the above commands is

```
ZRANGE "MO\\" 0 -1
1) "MOTEST"
2) "MO\\TEST"
```

In above case:- Single backslash is skipped when inserted with a single backslash,  and two backslashes are returned with two backslashes.

One more issue, I face that, If I use single quotes in value, Redis is returning me 4 '\' characters

```
ZADD "MO\\" 67 'MO\\TEST'
```

The output is:-

```
ZRANGE "MO\\" 0 -1
"MO\\\\TEST"
```

Comment: Seems like serializer issues. Can you verify what serializer you used in Redis client library?